# Partially merge to list in python

Tags: python

Classic, but i'm new to python... and have a problem a can't manage to solve. I'm assuming it's fairly easy.

I have two csv files, one scraped from the web(a=[]), containing 20000+ lines, the other exported from a local system [b=[]] 80+ lines.
I have open the files and stored the data in list a and b. Theey are structured like the example below.

```
a = [[1,'a','b','a@b',11],
    [2,'c','d','c@b',22],
    [3,'e','f','e@b',33]]

b = [['a','banana','A',100],
    ['e','apple','A',100]]
```

Now i would like to go through list a and when index 1 of every sublist in list a is equal to index 0 of the sublist in list b it shall append index 3 and 4 of a. So I would end up with

```
 c=  [['a','banana','A',100,'a@b',11],
        ['e','apple','A',100,'e@b',33],]
```

How to achive this. The solution don't need to be fast if it teaches something about the structure in Python. But if solved easy with pandas i'm all ears.
If this fora is not for questions like this i'm sorry for the time.

Comment: In `a` is there only one sublist with index 1 == 'a'? In `b` is there only one sublist with index 0 == 'a'?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I will try better next time. I was trying to get a pointer in the right direction more as a complete solution, as this is just a part of the problem I trying to solve. Maybe just a signal of frustration on my side, of being stucked for to long :) Have a great time and thanks for the reply.

Comment: @wwii, no in a there can a there can bed multiple sublist == 'a', in b there will be only one. Ultimately it is b that needs extra data.

Comment: You could tell us _where_ you're stuck, since I'm sure you got somewhere with your attempt! What went wrong? Where do you think it went wrong? What did you expect to happen? Did you try any [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? If you [stepped through your code in a debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173), what did you see happening? The [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953) is a good place to start. Seeing your approach helps people build off it, and lets you understand where you went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Refering to your comment below: "From tour: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.". Do you have any tips for a more beginner focused fora. I'm just trying to learn this as hobby.

Comment: @CasperHelmark I'm not really sure of a forum for that (note: StackOverflow is pretty adamant about not being a forum). But [Real Python](https://realpython.com/) has some of the best beginner tutorials, and [Trey Hunner](https://treyhunner.com/)'s articles are excellent, though I've never tried his "Morsels" exercises.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not optimized and isn't efficient time complexity vice, but it's readable and does the job.

```py
c = []
for a_entry in a:
   for b_entry in b:
       if a_entry[1] == b_entry[0]:
           c.append(b_entry + a_entry[3:])
```

Comment: Let's not reward questions that show no effort on OP's part with answers! From [answer], you should answer well-asked questions, and well-asked questions usually include a [mre] and a specific question

Comment: You provided the answer but you didn't explain how? It is not gonna help OP in any meaningful way. They will be just dependent on someone else to do their job. explain your thought process in the answer.

Comment: Pointing out the rules of the site to newcomers isn't toxic, and I'm sorry you believe it is. From [tour]: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for **professional and enthusiast programmers**. If one has no programming knowledge, one doesn't have the ability to understand any answers and is just using SO as a crowdsourcing tool to do one's job for oneself.

Comment: So this iterates over a_entry and b_entry, compare a_entry[1] and b_entry[0] and if it matches append the hole sublist of b_entry at from [3:] of a_entry?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @CasperHelmark.
One possible optimization would be to use dictionaries instead.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem and I can move on.

Answer (score -1):

- make a dictionary (`{index1:[index2,index3],...}`) by iterating over `a`

  - for each item/sublist use index 1 for the key and indices 2 and 3 for the value
- do the same thing for `b` except use index zero for the key and `[1:]` for the value
- iterate over the items in the *`b`* dictionary

  - use the key of each item to get a value from the *`a`* dictionary

    - if there is one, extend the *`b`* item's value
- reconstruct `b` from the modified dictionary

Comment: Why bother making a dictionary out of `b`? You could just iterate directly over it, referring to your `a` dict to make `c`.

Comment: Thanks I will try and read up on using dictionaries, and try at some point an update the my code.

Comment: @CrazyChucky - i just liked the idea. Who knows I may need to use it again and again. dictionaries are useful. Was that your DV? Or by showing its usefulness maybe the dict can be made when reading the csv ....